# is there a way to set a background of a paragraph to reach all the way mid paragraph, but also end when the paragraph ends

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, styling

I'm trying to create something like this:
[mocked up ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ByQx.png)

Where one set of paragraph is followed by an arrow (mui icon) and followed by a new set of text. But for their background colour to reach the edge of the container. Also ideally without any line gap, but not too fussed about that.

This is the closest I could get, which isn't too bad, but I couldn't add padding to the sides of the text at the beginning and end of lines. If at least i could add padding then that might be enough.
[initial tries of implementing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx3Iq.png)

Experimented with different spans and paragraphs but nothing worth noting... nothing worked. How could I do this?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ve-ve/pen/poqqMjd

```css
.style {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.span1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px/* this doesnt apply to the edges */
}

.span2 {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class='style'>
  <span class='span1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
  <span>
    -> 
<!--     Ideally this is a mui icon -->
  </span>
  <span class='span2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
</div>
<!-- Doesnt work with <p> either? -->
```

Comment: Please include the code in your question.

Comment: _"But for their background colour to reach the edge of the container."_ - CSS has no built-in "mechanism" for that. With a `block` or `inline-block` element, the background color will extend over the _whole_ block covered by the element, not "lines of text" - and with an `inline` element, it won't go all the way to the edge, but only as far as the text requires.

Comment: Coloring the background of "lines" can be done by using a repeating linear gradient, although that usually requires some fiddling with the values, to take line-height etc. into account correctly. But even using those, I think you will have a hard time here getting the "break" inside of one lines to look exactly as desired.

Comment: Can we jump to the conclusion that by `mui` you mean MaterialUI and you have not properly tagged your question with that?

Comment: yeah I dont know how to add a material ui icon in codepen. But the focus is on the background colour of the text